# Should we merge the tags neural-networks and deep-neural-networks?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have three very related tags

1. [neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks)
2. [deep-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-neural-networks)
3. [deep-learning](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning)

The second could be merged with the first because it's partially redundant, and

1. the definition of a a deep neural network is a bit fuzzy
2. we can use the first and third tags when talking about deep neural networks (whatever that really means)
3. people may use the three tags when only 2 of them are probably necessary

However, it's also true that having all three tags is not a big problem. People may use the second tag without using the other 2 just because they want to know specifically about the architecture of a deep neural network without caring about learning. We also have examples of other tags that are very specific (e.g. [deterministic-policy](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deterministic-policy)), which some people could argue are not really necessary (and [policies](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policies) would be sufficient maybe in combination with the a tag that doesn't yet exist [determinism](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/determinism)). In the past, we also had the tag [strong-ai](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strong-ai), which was merged with [agi](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agi), as they are often synonyms.

In conclusion, I think I am in favour of the merge because deep neural networks are neural networks but with "more layers" (which is vague), but, apart from that, they don't have anything special. What is really more special is "deep learning", i.e. learning techniques for neural networks that have "many layers".

Comment: I guess it would make much more sense to consider merging [tag:deep-neural-networks] with [tag:deep-learning] (they are practically synonyms), rather than with the more generic tag [tag:neural-networks].

Comment: @desertnaut My main thesis is: "deep neural networks" are not well defined. They are neural networks that are deep, but what "deep" means is not well-defined. DL, on the other hand, is concerned with learning in NNs where problems like the "vanishing gradient" occur, so the DL term actually refers to some specific problems and algorithms. The reason why I suggested to merge with NNs is because DNNs are NNs, they are not deep learning. Deep Learning is about learning, i.e. algorithms like gradient descent. However, it doesn't really matter with which tag we merge DNNs - both are fine, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is okay to keep intact as there is a fundamental difference between them both in the technical and historical arena.

It is true that deep neural networks form at most a subset of neural networks but have a uniqueness in terms of representation as mentioned in [this quote](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/bengio13.html)

> It has been hypothesized, and supported with experimental evidence,
> that deeper representations, when well trained, tend to do a better
> job at disentangling the underlying factors of variation.

Although your proposal is considerable, most people are habituated to using neural networks for generic architectures as well as for those with fewer layers and deep neural networks for more focused architectures. So, I believe that it will be useful to keep them intact as it attracts more questions from deep neural networks with few tags attached.

Comment: It seems that deeper networks can learn certain representations better, but a single hidden layer neural network is, in theory, as powerful as a deep one. So, I am not sure if there's a "fundamental difference". Anyway, my concern is that the definition of "deep neural network" is unclear, as far as I know - there's no solid science that tells that certain NNs are deep while others aren't. This can lead to a misuse of the tag [tag:deep-neural-networks] - this is one reason why I am in favour of the merge.

Comment: For example, I think it makes more sense to have the tag [tag:deterministic-policy] because its definition is quite widely accepted in RL (the only concern is whether we would have enough questions about this topic or not to have a dedicated tag for it). So, there isn't much room for ambiguity and misuse of this tag. Having said that, [tag:deep-neural-networks] wouldn't be misused so badly - people would still talk about neural networks. That's why I think it wouldn't be a big problem to also keep this tag.

Comment: These example questions highlight the need for different tags: "[Need help in debugging **Shallow** Neural network using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62576811/3648282)", "[Training speed on a **shallow** neural network with a small dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53290220/3648282)", "[A Logistic Regression with Neural Network mindset VS a **shallow** Neural Network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/366707/197829)", "[Does Deep network (e.g. # of hidden layer=2) always better than **shallow** network (i.e. # of hidden layer=1)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/120840/197829)",etc.

Comment: @Rob Those questions were not asked on AISE. Anyway, I know that there are some questions where this tag would be somehow appropriate. My main point is that the term "deep neural network" is not well-defined.

Comment: @nbro, the prior comment was written to support hanugm's answer, but I welcome your input. The first, second, and shallow -n-n, are three separate tags, as explained in this link list: https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-write-a-tag-wiki-excerpt#comment430_192 to the FAQ, and related examples. If it's unclear if it's shallow, deep, or even long the catch-all first tag is available - that's why there's umbrella tags in addition to more specific ones.

Comment: @nbro, if examples from this site are preferable we can search here for: [shallow+neural+networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/search?q=shallow+neural+networks); it shows how people have tagged, sometimes with deep-* and often with the umbrella tag [tag:neural-networks] ([tag:shallow-neural-networks] being missing) - probably time better spent checking the tagging, before or instead of [burnifying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info).

Comment: @Rob Can you define what a deep and shallow neural network is? People will answer by saying a DNN is a neural network with many layers, say, more than 10 or 20. Ok, I say that this is not a standard definition, AFAIK. Why don't we choose to define DNNs as NNs with more than 3 layers? AFAIK, there isn't a standard "scientific" definition of what DNNs, although people talk about "them", without knowing what they are really referring to exactly. It's like talking about "intelligence". Everyone talks about it, but often people are not talking about same thing or are masking different assumptions.

Comment: Again, I am not saying that it's completely a mistake to have the tag DNN. It's not a big problem. Maybe the problem is to well define what a DNN is or for the AI community to agree upon a single definition, and then retag questions currently tagged with DNN appropriately, if they are not. What I think is a mistake is to have a tag which can be misused. Tags should be used for specific purposes. So, when people need to search for questions, they can narrow the list of questions down using the tags.

Comment: In response to [this comment](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/should-we-merge-the-tags-neural-networks-and-deep-neural-networks/2872?noredirect=1#comment3521_2872), A simpler explanation of shallow is here: https://towardsdatascience.com/shallow-neural-networks-23594aa97a5 - shallow is easier to understand, good for learning or in instances where it is suitable (quick implementation / local memory) but deep is better for overall speed:  https://qr.ae/pvCYoP but too deep isn't *better* https://qr.ae/pvCYPk - more than a few layers is deep (IMO, and somewhat agreed upon).

Comment: In response to "... What I think is a mistake is to have a tag which can be misused. Tags should be used for specific purposes.". All tags can be *misused*, what's important is a clear excerpt and for users with edit privilege (even suggested edits) to spruce and prune the tags proposed by the asker; who might be in need of help, both with the question itself but also the use of tags here.